# Windows 8 RP says no network adapter found under boot camp in the new Retina MBP. Can anyone help me get the driver for the network adapter?

Tags: windows, bootcamp, network, macbook-pro

http://www.anandtech.com/show/6008/windows-8-on-the-retina-display-macbook-pro

"The problem is Apple doesn't provide a Boot Camp driver set for the Retina MacBook Pro yet. I had to use the Broadcom wireless driver from my SNB MacBook Pro to get WiFi working under Windows."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a bit more of searching online, found the driver, installed it and it works. Here's the link for anyone else who might need: http://www.wireless-driver.com/broadcom-wireless-driver-utility-winxp-vista-win7-ver51001968/

Thanks.

Comment: This worked for windows 8 ? the site says `Broadcom 802.11n Wireless LAN Win2000, WinXP, Vista, Win7 32/64bit Drivers and Utility, Ver.5.100.196.81:`

Answer (score 1):

you need to download the latest apple support for windows, am loving my apple as it is and the bootcamp is just the icing i needed on the cake.. Ahhhhhhhhhh Loving it!!!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ask Different! Can you please you expand on your answer? Maybe a link and some instructions to the "latest apple support for windows" software you're referencing? As written, this answer is very low quality. For more information on how to answer questions please see our (FAQ)[http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq].

Comment: As said above, you answer the question, but all those little extras (links to support, forums, etc) are what really make an answer great. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Retina Macbook Pro but what I would do in your case:
Download trial of [Aida64](http://www.aida64.com/downloads). It will help to detect network chip, then go to manufacturer's site and download drivers (probably that would be Windows 7 ones) for that chip.

Comment: Thanks, will try that out. But I can't go online without the driver so doubt Aida64 will help.

Comment: Anand notes in his website that it's the same card as the 2011 MBPs so the driver should be the same. It's the Broadcom BCM4331 single-chip 802.11n dual-band wireless solution adapter.